# Deduced Return Type

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Container, typename Index>
decltype(auto)
foo(Container&& c, Index i) {
    return std::forward<Container>(c)[i];
}

template<typename Container, typename Index>
decltype(auto)
bar(Container&& c, Index i) {
    return c[i];
}

int main() {
    std::vector<uint32_t> q{1, 3, 5};
    std::vector<uint32_t> r{2, 4, 6};

    std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(q, 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar(q, 1) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(std::move(q), 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar(std::move(r), 1) << std::endl;
}
```

What's the difference between the return types of `foo()` and `bar()`?

`std::forward<Container>(c)` just keeps its "original" type.  How does it affect the turn type?  As it seems to me, when `c` is a rvalue reference, `std::forward<Container>(c)[i]` still returns a reference to the i-th element; when `c` is lvalue reference, `std::forward<Container>(c)[i]` still returns a reference to the i-th element.

I am sure I miss something.

Comment: Does anyone know what happens if `foo` is used with a temporary? Like `auto val = foo(std::vector<int>{3,2,1},1)`. My feeling is, that this produces a reference to a deleted value, which would be undefined behaviour. Is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector::operator[]` doesn't have overload for rvalue this. so in your case, there are no changes.

but for class like:

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    T operator [](std::size_t) &&;
    T& operator [](std::size_t) &;
    // ...
};
```

it would make a difference.